# How can i send the char of the measured temperature, so it will be viewable in my serial capture program (using Realterm or Putty)

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, avr

I want to send the measured temperature to my uart on my Arduino with this code. I have used this code plenty times and the transmit always work. But when i want to send this I dont get the output that I want in my realterm serial capture program. The code for converting it to celsius is probably good but i end up having a float that I probably need to convert to a char (maybe with sprintf() or something) but im just stuck with this at the moment.

Ive tried multiple ways of doing this but the problem is that there is possibly only one way of doing it. I also tried using itoa(temperature, buffer, 10); Its a bit hard to actually find out what i have to do to convert it in such a way that it will be visible in my serial capture program. The baudrate is set correct to 19200. In the start of the program the uart will be initialised after that I call the transmit function in the main within the loop.

```
//while(1)
        int reading = ADCsingleREAD(0); //Reads the sensor on port 0

        float voltage = reading * (5.0f / 1024.0f);

        float temperature = (voltage - 0.5f) * 100;

        char a = temperature;

        //Maybe i also need to do this ?
        //  char array[10];
        //  sprintf(array, "%f", temperature);

        transmit(temperature);
        _delay_ms(100);


        //the transmit function (in a different file)
        void transmit(int8_t data)
        {
            // wait for an empty transmit buffer
            // UDRE is set when the transmit buffer is empty
            loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
            // send the data
            UDR0 = data;
        }
```

Comment: `buffer` is a misleading name for a single byte, and it's undefined in your snippet.

Comment: Yes I was testing with a char array called buffer but i ment to transmit the float temperature. (changed it)

Comment: That should give you a compiler error

Answer (score 0):

Typically Serial terminal programs show text, so you should transmit text:

e.g. "20.5" if it is really intended to be a float
or  "20" as this precision is sufficient and easier to handle

(additionally, newline characters are recommended)

Arduino does not support %f format in sprintf directly. Either use the Arduino print(float) method for any class derived from Stream, or `dtostrf`.

A single byte with the value of 20 isn't a printable character, but can of course be interpreted as intended by your own software on the receiving device.

Comment: But why is it possible to send a char from my realterm serial program and receive it back via UART (with a receive function). But when i send a char via code to UART it wont be displayable.

Comment: if you send a printable char ( 33 .. 127 ) it will be printed. 65 is an `'A'` for example. A space ( 32 ) will be printed too, but is harder to see :)